# Responsive data tables horizontal scroll without framwork

Tags: html, css

I'm looking for a bootstrap like responsive table solution but without the whole bootstrap Javascript and CSS because the site I'm using it is working without any frameworks (from scratch). 
Demo: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_table-responsive&stacked=h

Is there any simple solution to create such an effect with CSS and simple Javascript or a jQuery plugin? I checked different solutions but couldn't find such a simple one which just adds a vertical scroll bar.

Comment: Look at the bootstrap source and duplicate the part you need. You don't need the whole library.

Comment: add a wrapper div with `min-width` and `overflow-x:auto;`. give table width to  required pixels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all you need:

```
.yourTableClass {
  display: block;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
```

Test:

```css
table {
  display: block;
  overflow-x: auto;
}


/* you don't need the rules below! */
table {
  margin: 0 1rem;
}
td {
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 3px 8px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th> 1 </th>
    <th> 2 </th>
    <th> 3 </th>
    <th> 4 </th>
    <th> 5 </th>
    <th> 6 </th>
    <th> 7 </th>
    <th> 8 </th>
    <th> 9 </th>
    <th> 10 </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> first column</td>
    <td> second column</td>
    <td> third column</td>
    <td> fourth column</td>
    <td> fifth column</td>
    <td> sixth column</td>
    <td> seventh column</td>
    <td> eighth column</td>
    <td> nineth column</td>
    <td> tenth column</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```